# How to use selected value of dropdown into text of another label in Apache Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a dropdown list in Apache Velocity and I need to use selected value of dropdown as text for a label:

```html
<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

This is my label:

```html
<label id="selectedValue""> //I need value of selected value here </label>
```

How do I use a selected value from Dropdown into text of another label in apache velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/derrysan7/qLew1hx6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#fruits').on('change', function(){
            var selected_fruits = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

            $("#selectedValue").empty();
            $('#selectedValue').append(selected_fruits);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi thanks but i was just curious if we can somehow do it without jquery or javascript using apache velocity

Comment: No you can't, what you are trying to do is changing client side html element, so you need client side language like javascript and jquery..

Comment: If you really want to use server side language, you can use ajax to send the selected value to server, use that value to select from database, and then convert the select result to json, then pass the json to the label.... But, as you can see, its just not practical for a simple task like this